# Computed entity, in Doctrine2?

Tags: mysql, inheritance, doctrine-orm, doctrine, associations

In Doctrine2, is there a way to create a computed entity, that is based on the results of a complex sql query?

**Background**:

In an application that I'm working on (existed prior to my joining the project), there is a concept of:
attribute (belongs to attribute, has many attribute, **overrides** attribute)
catalogItem (belongs to catalogItem, has many catalogItem, has many attribute)

The idea is that catalogItem has it's own hierarchy, that currently goes up to 4 levels deep.
Each catalogItem inherits the attributes of it's parent, but those attributes (which have their own hierarchy as well) can be overridden at any point.
This overridden hierarchy is then used by the immediate catalogItem, and it's children as well, with the same ability existing to create overrides.

As a result, the typical structure of direct associations is fairly useless here, since we're always needing to see the computed end-result.

So, my issue is, I would like to be able to inject these computed results into Doctrine2, which can then be used as standard entities, which ability to traverse relations, etc, as normal.

This can't be done as a MySQL view, as performance drops. Additionally, the query that creates the computed result is fairly complex, and for performance, any filtering (say, by X catalogItem) occurs at both a 3rd level nested subquery, as well as the top-level query, and the very existence of subqueries means a normal MySQL view is directly incompatible (though there are workarounds).

**Question**:

I would like to be able to create an entity in Doctrine2, for which instead of a "table" existing, the actual MySQL query would exist, and would be run as a subquery.
I haven't yet seen any way in Doctrine2 to achieve something like what I'm describing, I'm hoping someone can present a solution or workaround to achieve a similar result?

Comment: Just a note, I already have my complex SQL query set up as a Doctrine2 native query, and mapped into entities for the results. That's not really what I'm looking for though, since it doesn't live as an entity that can be related against. I'm looking for a result that allows the computed entity to act as a normal Doctrine2 entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to handle this kind of logic with Doctrine ORM.
The ORM thinks in statically typed entities that are associated and have an unique identifier (from the definition of entity).

Also, the values and the type of those entities should not change dynamically, since the ORM can't handle type casting.

What you can do is:

1. defining a mysql-level view
2. creating an entity that is marked as `@Entity(readOnly=true)`, which will be ignored by the ORM on flushes

This way, the ORM will be able to read data from your entity using the normal [persisters](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/tree/2.3.2/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Persisters), and you will be able to use the identifiers of your object in associations.

If your entity type is computed, consider emulating a [single table inheritance](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#single-table-inheritance) with a discriminator column in your view.

Comment: STI/Inheritance isn't applicable here. When I say that the data is computed, that is to say, I'm trying to reflect the state of an attribute tree for any given catalogItem. A view won't suffice due to limitations in MySQL, and it appears I can't specify a query-only approach in Doctrine2. Actually, I could if I were allowed to override the default persisters, but that isn't allowed in Doctrine2 yet...

Comment: @JonL. then you'll need to fallback to NativeSQL anyway. That's what a persister does anyway (internally)

Comment: That's what I'm trying to solve, since doctrine entity doesn't provide access to Entity Manager, which means NativeQuery will complicate usage. Seems like a bit of a lose/lose situation :-\

Comment: @JonL. well, that happens when you hit the limits of the tool. You probably want to move those associations to the service layer then.

Comment: that's what I've had to do. The limitations in Doctrine2 seem to get a bit more noticeable each day, so I find I'm having to come up with poor workarounds for situations that are easily solved in another ORM/AR tool, such as Yii's own ActiveRecord. (For instance, a "has many through" relationship can be mapped easily in Yii, not so in Doctrine2).   Bah... Anywho, I'm marking your answer as correct.   Do you have any thoughts on Propel v. Doctrine?

Comment: @JonL. you can't ask me if I have un-biased opinions on Doctrine if Doctrine is a tool I help developing myself :) Propel is active query by the way, which *could* be what you are looking for. Another way is Zend\Db, which uses a table data gateway, and should be ok to handle such complex use cases (also there: no relations out of the service layer!)